# Improper ssl and virtualhost configuration

Tags: apache, ssl, https, httpd.conf, rhel

I am trying to set up all of my companies websites on a single LAMP machine (using RHEL6).  The issue I am having is that I need a certain subdomain to only be accessible by ssl.  I have scoured the internet for days looking for the proper way to do this, but I have not found a solution that works (for me) yet.  I have tryed createing a `.htaccess` file in the directory of the subdomain, and using RewriteRule, but that hasn't worked.  I also tried putting `SSLRequireSSL` into my httpd.conf file in the VirtualHost, but it didn't work(On a side note, do you put `SSLRequireSSL` into the *:80 virtual host or the *:443 one?). I am unsure whether we have mod_rewrite on the server(I will check and edit this).

Below is my VirtualHost code.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:443
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin netadmin@domain1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain1.com/
    Servername domain1.com
    ServerAlias www.domain1.com
    ErrorLog logs/localerror
    CustomLog logs/accesslog common
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin netadmin@domain1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain2.co.uk/
    ServerName domain2.co.uk
    ServerAlias www.domain2.co.uk
    ErrorLog logs/localerror
    CustomLog logs/accesslog common
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin netadmin@domain1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain1.com/logo
    Servername logo.domain1.com
    ServerAlias www.logo.domain1.com
    ErrorLog logs/localerror
    CustomLog logs/accesslog common
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/server.key
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin netadmin@domain1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain1.com/
    Servername domain1.com
    ServerAlias domain1.com www.domain1.com
    ErrorLog logs/localerror
    CustomLog logs/accesslog common
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/server.key
</VirtualHost>
```

Just to be clear, I want it to be possible to access the entire site with ssl, but have it only be *required* on the subdomain logo.domain1.com .

EDIT: We do have mod_ssl and mod_rewrite installed.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any programming involved, so this should probably go on ServerFault or SuperUser, but while you ponder, have you tried: `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` followed by `RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}`?

Comment: Yes I have. It did not work.